# Using Ajax/JQuery to check original password as user types

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'd like to allow the user to type in their original password, on the Change Password page, and have the page check whether it is correct or not without a refresh.  I'd like a checkbox image to appear next to the text box when the password is correct.

I have two issues, though. 1) how can this be done in a secure manner, and 2) firing an ajax call with every keypress does not seem to always catch each keypress.

This is what I have so far:

```
$("#oldPW").keyup(function () {
    checkPW();
});

// on keyup
function checkPW() {
    var pw = $("#oldPW").val();
    var dataSring = "pw=" + pw;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkPW",
        data: dataSring,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data== "True") {
                $("#pwok").fadeIn();
            }
            if (data== "false") {
                $("#pwok").fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I see that the problem with the above code is that the user could manually show the image, which would bypass the above "security".  I could check again after the user presses submit, but that does not address problem 1, missing keyups, and I'm not sure if it is foolproof in terms of security either.

Comment: That seems really wasteful of resources for very little actual benefit. I'm also not sure what harm there is in the user showing the image - surely the image itself doesn't grant them any particular privileges.  You might also want to be careful in case the backend locks the user out after a certain number of failures. Someone with a long password would never be able to login.

Comment: Could you do it on 'blur' or have the keypress start a timeout that waits 1500 ms before submitting and clears the previous timeout started

Comment: Likwid, that might work in terms of the keypress problem.  I was also concern about the user being able to fake the authentication in the code.  Not sure how to avoid that.  Is it possible to do it in a secure manner?  Just checking.

Comment: tvanfosson, Thanks, I will check the number of failed attempts as you say.  That's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem #1, you need to validate the password on the server side *regardless*.  Then, you won't have to worry about someone bypassing the client side.

As for #2, the problem is that you don't know what order the ajax calls will complete in, so a previous call may finish after the latest call.  You can handle this in a lot of ways, but one is to abort the request each time you try again:

```
$("#oldPW").data('lastRequest', {abort: function () {}});

function checkPW() {
    var pw = $("#oldPW").val();
    var dataSring = "pw=" + pw;
    $("#oldPW").data('lastRequest').abort();
    $("#oldPW").data('lastRequest', $.ajax({
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Do you think keyup is the best event to use, or should I use a blur as Likwid recommends?

Comment: @Dave the only thing about using `blur` is that it requires you to .. blur.  You could just make it trigger when they click the "Submit" button or whatever

Comment: True, but there is a certain appeal to having an immediate response from the page as the user types.  Missing keyups is an issue in another project I have where people like the immediate feedback.  But I was not trying the abort method.  I've read about it but this is the first sample code I've seen.